# Excel VBA: Copying a column to another sheet when criteria is met

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset with names in column A and either a Yes or No in column B for each one.
I want to do the following:

If values in **Column A Sheet 1** have a **Yes** in **Column B Sheet 1**, then copy only these values to **Column A in Sheet 2**

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim name As Long
Worksheets("Sheet2").Select

name = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Select
       
       Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
       Selection.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(name, 1)
End Sub
```

How can I get this code to only copy the values in column A that has a **Yes** in column B to Sheet2?

Comment: Use `Range.AutoFilter` or `Range.AdvancedFilter`.

Comment: After the filter, you will need to use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to copy the visible data only.

Comment: Thank you very much @BigBen.

Comment: Thanks @GMalc for replying. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy With Criteria

- Adjust the values in the **const**ants section to fit your needs.

**'Looping Through Each Cell' Version**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyCriteria()
    
    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const ValueColumn As Variant = "A"      ' e.g. 1 or "A"
    Const CriteriaColumn As Variant = "B"   ' e.g. 1 or "A"
    Const srcFirstRow As Long = 2
    
    ' Target
    Const tgtName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const tgtColumn As Variant = "A"        ' e.g. 1 or "A"
    Const tgtFirstRow As Long = 2
    
    ' Other
    Const Criteria As String = "Yes"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Calculate Source Last Row.
    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = wb.Worksheets(srcName)
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, ValueColumn).End(xlUp)
    Dim srcLastRow As Long: srcLastRow = rng.Row
    If srcLastRow < srcFirstRow Then Exit Sub
                                    
    ' Looping through cells in Criteria Column, check if the value
    ' in each cell is equal to Criteria. If it is then write the 'corresponding'
    ' value from Value Column to Target Column.
    Dim tgt As Worksheet: Set tgt = wb.Worksheets(tgtName)
    Dim tgtRow As Long: tgtRow = tgtFirstRow - 1
    Dim i As Long
    For i = srcFirstRow To srcLastRow
        If src.Cells(i, CriteriaColumn).Value = Criteria Then
            tgtRow = tgtRow + 1
            tgt.Cells(tgtRow, tgtColumn).Value = src.Cells(i, ValueColumn).Value
        End If
    Next i
 
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Copied '" & tgtRow - tgtFirstRow + 1 & "' values.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @VBasic2008 for taking out the time to write this.